# typedef ignored on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

Really simple, this photo explains the problem, Visual Studio 2017 error: **variable "InputCode" is not a type name**

[image]

```
#ifndef INPUT_H
#define INPUT_H

typedef unsigned InputCode;

struct KeyboardInfo
{
    char *name; /* OS dependant name; 0 terminates the list */
    unsigned code; /* OS dependant code */
    InputCode standardcode; /* CODE_xxx equivalent from list below, or CODE_OTHER if n/a */
};
#endif
```

Comment: It should probably read `typedef unsigned int InputCode`. This looks like antiquated C code where `int` was often implicit and cuold be omitted. Same for `unsigned code`, which should probably be `unsigned int code`.

Comment: BTW why do you post a picture of your code (and cutting off the potentially interesting comments). Post text as text.

Comment: **unsigned** is an alias for **unsigned int**

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: @Francesco Not when it comes to code. Can you copy paste the picture and run it locally?

Comment: Tagged C _and_ C++11. Which one is it?

Comment: You are going to need more words.  IntelliSense squiggles can be misleading, post the actual compile error messages.  All of them.  If you copy/pasted this code then consider that it may contain a non-printing Unicode codepoint.

Comment: @Biffen Visual Studio doesn't allow you to select a C project. It is always a C++ project that can contains C code

Comment: @HansPassant I'll check

Comment: @Jabberwocky — using just `unsigned` to mean `unsigned int` is explicitly blessed in the C standard. If the IDE misinterprets that line, the IDE has problems.

Comment: @Jabberwocky  also intellisense is famed for ability to "forget" last edits to code, so if you changed declaration and added a typedef or macro.. it ignores last two and still squiggles the code out. Curiously, I sopped correlation between such errors (obviously a data race of sorts) and presence of antivirus programs. Inetellisense is running an instance SQL engine and it  may experience interference if something else accesses that database.

Comment: Please do not change title to include a "SOLVED" tag. Instead simply accept the answer that solved the problem. If there was no useful answer, you can write your own answer (as you already did) and accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that the problem was not in the first error obtained during compilation but in an error that was reported later. Very strange behaviour, using gcc or g++ the first reported error always is the problem

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the code presented, neither when interpreted as C nor when interpreted as C++.

In particular, contrary to some of the commentary on the question, `unsigned` is a Standard-supported alias for `unsigned int` in both languages, just as `long` is a Standard supported alias for `long int`.  There is thus no inherent problem with the `typedef` declaration itself, which, indeed, VS *does not* flag.

Wherever a `typedef` declaration is in scope, the identifier it declares -- `InputCode` in this case -- is valid for use as a type name, exactly as the code seems to expect.  There is therefore no problem with the `struct KeyboardInfo` declaration, either.

If the Visual Studio compiler or IDE complains about the code presented then that constitutes a flaw in Visual Studio.  However, you might find that VS compiles the code successfully despite the IDE flagging an issue in it.

Comment: As I wrote before, **unsigned** is an alias for **unsigned int**